# Calculating discharge on the pipe diameter and the pressure?

Tags: pressure, hydraulics, piping, pipelines

Is it possible to сalculate discharge / flow rate on the pipe diameter and the pressure (for constant pressure)?

For example:

[image]

`Pressure_internal = 5 bar`, `Diameter_pipe = 36 mm`, `Density_water = 1000 kg/m^3`

Bernoulli's Formula [(online calculation)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%285-1%29%5Bbar%5D+*+2+%2F+%281000+%5Bkg%2Fm%5E3%5D%29%29+to+%5Bm%2Fs%5D):

$$\frac{\rho v^2}{2} + \rho g h + p = const$$

$$v \approx \sqrt{(p_i-p_a)\frac{2}{\rho_w}} = \sqrt{(5 \mathrm{bar}-1 \mathrm{bar})\frac{2}{1000 \frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{m}^3} }}=28.284 \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}}$$

Then the discharge should be [(online calculation)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%20*%20%2818%5Bmm%5D%20%29%5E2%20*%2028.284%5Bm%2Fs%5D%20to%20%5Bl%2Fmin%5D):

$$Q = Sv = (\pi r^2) v = \pi * (18\mathrm{mm})^2 *28.284\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}} = 1717.81 \frac{\mathrm{l}}{\mathrm{min}}$$

But these values are very far from reality. How can I perform a calculation correct?

Comment: What reality are you seeing? This simple analysis appears to ignore factors like viscosity, friction in the pipe, turbulence and so on - however it can place a useful bound on the discharge rate.

Comment: As @BrianDrummond points out, this formulation ignores the key variable that determine the flow.  You need to account for the length of the pipe, the friction in the pipe, the physical properties of the liquid, whether the flow is laminar or turbulent, and entrance and exit losses.  The place to start is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy-Weisbach_equation

Comment: all muliplications are wrong please check

Comment: @OASISPOOLS I have added a link to an online calculator.
Which of the calculations do you think is wrong?

Comment: Are you multiplying the area in mm^2 by velocity in m/s ? make sure your units agree.

Comment: @SolarMike I am sure (see attached links).

Comment: Well, if i do the last calculation you show then my result is 0.0288 L/sec ie 1.73 L/min.

Comment: @SolarMike You get the result in cubic meters per second [m^3/s].

Comment: Then I suggest you check all the units you are using, perhaps the pressure difference should be in Pascals...

Comment: @SolarMike I rechecked all the mathematical transformations many times, and you can also verify this through Wolfram|Alpha service. The problem here is that all hydrodynamic effects are ignored here. So most likely a reference to Darcy–Weisbach equation may be the right answer to this question.

Comment: So do that and find out.